# Project raster to new extent

Tags: raster, r

I have some data in a raster stack (CCSM4 climate projections from 2010 - 2300) that I've done some processing on, but now I would like to change the extent. I'm not 100% sure how to do this in R. So far I've tried `Extent`, `Origin`, `projectExtent`, `projectRaster`, but haven't had any luck. Below are two images showing the issue I'm having and the results of what I've tried, and a reproducible example

Here is my original dataset, the extent is

```
> extent(pr_ccsm4_2.5deg)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -0.625 
xmax        : 359.375 
ymin        : -89.5288 
ymax        : 90.4712
```

[image: Original Dataset]

What I would like to do is get the data to have an extent of

```
> extent(ras25)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : -180 
xmax        : 180 
ymin        : -90 
ymax        : 90
```

I thought that I could simply change the extent using `extent(pr_ccsm4_2.5deg) <- extent(ras25)`, however this results in my data looking like this
[image: altered extent]

So now, while the extent is correct, the data is not projected properly.

Here is a reproducible example

```
library(rworldmap)
library(cleangeo)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

# continental shapefile
cont <- getMap()
cont <- clgeo_Clean(cont)
cont <- sapply(levels(cont$continent),
               FUN = function(i){
                 poly <- gUnionCascaded(subset(cont, continent == i))
                 poly <- spChFIDs(poly, i)
                 SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(poly, data.frame(continent = i, row.names = i))
               }, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
cont <- Reduce(spRbind, cont)

ras <- raster(xmn = 0, xmx = 360, ymn = -90, ymx = 90, res = 2.5)
values(ras) <- runif(n = ncell(ras), 0, 1)
ras
> ras
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 72, 144, 10368  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 2.5, 2.5  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 360, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 2.22486e-05, 0.9998961  (min, max)
# Wrong extent
rasterVis::levelplot(ras, margin = NA, par.settings = RdBuTheme) + layer(sp.polygons(cont))
```

[image: wrong extent raster]

```
ras2 <- raster(xmn = -180, xmx = 180, ymn = -90, ymx = 90, res = 2.5)
values(ras2) <- runif(n = ncell(ras2), 0, 1)
ras2
> ras2
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 72, 144, 10368  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 2.5, 2.5  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 0.0001686567, 0.9998712  (min, max)

# Correct extent
rasterVis::levelplot(ras2, margin = NA, par.settings = RdBuTheme) + layer(sp.polygons(cont))
```

[image: correct extent raster]

```
rasPrj <- projectRaster(ras, ras2, over = FALSE)
rasPrj
# Correct extent, but missing data
rasterVis::levelplot(rasPrj, margin = NA, par.settings = RdBuTheme) + layer(sp.polygons(cont))
```

[image: correct extent, missing data]

Comment: Try `raster::rotate(pr_ccsm4_2.5deg)` which is for precisely this task. Note that the *after shifting* the hemisphere is probably `extent(-180, 180, -90, 90)` so you can just set that afterwards,  but you should check that carefully - there's often an ambiguity about  cell edge versus cell centre, but it's not always that straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mdsumner, I have no idea how I missed that when reading through the `raster` documentation.

Comment: rotate is a non-obvious name when thinking about an image!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `raster::rotate` which is for precisely this task.

I.e.

```
raster::rotate(pr_ccsm4_2.5deg)
```

Note that the after shifting the hemisphere is probably `extent(-180, 180, -90, 90)` so you can just set that afterwards, but you should check that carefully. There's often an ambiguity about cell-edge versus cell-centre, but it's not always that straightforward.